# How to sort List in dart based on value returned by a function

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart, location, distance

I have to show a list of stores in a sorted order by nearest location
 and I have a unsorted list of stores and a function to calculate
 distance of each store from my current location but I don't know how
 to sort List in dart based on value returned by a function.
 I am getting the unsorted List of stores data from an api.
 I need logic for this question for sorting the _kikkleStores List

```
  class KikkleStoresBloc extends BlocBase {
  List<KikkleStoreInfo> _kikkleStores = [];
  //for distance sorting
  List<KikkleStoreInfo> _kikkleStoresSorted = [];
  List<double> distanceFromCurrentLocation;//already got 
  value in it
  bool hasReachedEndOfList = false;
  Coordinate _currentLocation;

  KikkleStoresBloc();

  final _kikkleStoreSubject = 
  BehaviorSubject<List<KikkleStoreInfo>> 
  ();

  // Getter Stream
  Stream<List<KikkleStoreInfo>> get kikkleStores => 
  _kikkleStoreSubject.stream;`enter code here`

  // Getter Sink
  Function(List<KikkleStoreInfo>) get _fetchedkikkleStores =>
  _kikkleStoreSubject.sink.add;

  getKikkleStores() async {
    try {
      if (_currentPage <= _totalPages) {
        final response = await 
         ApiController.getKikkleStores(_currentPage);
        _kikkleStores.addAll(response.item1);



       //here how to sort _kikkleStores by using 
       getStoreDistance function



        _totalPages = response.item3;
        _fetchedkikkleStores(_kikkleStores);
        if (_currentPage == _totalPages) {
          hasReachedEndOfList = true;
        } else if (_currentPage < _totalPages && 
        _kikkleStores.length 
        < 10) {

              }
            } 
          } 
         }

  // this function returns distance 
  getStoreDistance(Coordinate currentLocation, KikkleStoreInfo 
  store) 
  async {
    if (currentLocation == null) return 0.0;
    try {
      double distanceInMeter = await 
      LocationUtils.getDistanceInMeters(
      currentLocation, Coordinate(store.latitude, 
      store.longitude));
      // final miles = (distanceInMeter / 1609.344).round();
      return distanceInMeter;
    } catch (e) {
      return 0.0;
    }
  }
  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      final isAllowed = await 
      PermissionsUtils.isLocationAccessAllowed();
      if (isAllowed) {
        final coordinates = await 
        LocationUtils.getCurrentLocation();
        if (coordinates != null) {
          _currentLocation = coordinates;
        }
      }
     } 
     catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take the reference of below code

```
void main(){
  List<POJO> pojo = [POJO(5), POJO(3),POJO(7),POJO(1)];
// fill list

pojo..sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
  for(var i in pojo){
    print(i.id);      // prints list in sorted order i.e 1 3 5 7
  }

}

class POJO {
  int id;

  POJO(this.id);
}
```

Comment: void sortKikkleStores() async {
    //sorting algo
    await _kikkleStores.sort((a, b) =>
        getStoreDistance(_currentLocation, a).compareTo(_currentLocation, b));
  } .

Comment: The app hangs when i try this function for sorting

Comment: @waqarsaeed  if your **KikkleStoreInfo** class has the property of **currentLocation** then after adding the objects<KikkleStoreInfo> to the list _kikkleStores do the sorting like this                                   `_kikkleStores.sort((a,b) => (a.currentLocation).compareTo(b.currentLocation));
for(var i in _kikkleStores) {
    print(i.currentLocation);     
  } `

Comment: finally Solved it.

Comment: void sortfun() async {
    for (int c = 0; c < (_kikkleStores.length - 1); c++) {
      for (int d = 0; d < _kikkleStores.length - c - 1; d++) {
        if (await getStoreDistance(_currentLocation, _kikkleStores[d]) >
            await getStoreDistance(_currentLocation,
                _kikkleStores[d + 1])) /* For descending order use < */
        {
          swap = _kikkleStores[d];
          _kikkleStores[d] = _kikkleStores[d + 1];
          _kikkleStores[d + 1] = swap;
        }
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
 void sortfun() async {
    for (int c = 0; c < (_kikkleStores.length - 1); c++) {
      for (int d = 0; d < _kikkleStores.length - c - 1; d++) {
        if (await getStoreDistance(_currentLocation, _kikkleStores[d]) >
            await getStoreDistance(_currentLocation,
                _kikkleStores[d + 1])) /* For descending order use < */
        {
          swap = _kikkleStores[d];
          _kikkleStores[d] = _kikkleStores[d + 1];
          _kikkleStores[d + 1] = swap;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```